# batch For loop execute command with multiple spaces in path

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Create Two folder with below names

```
One Space
Multiple         Space
```

Execute below commands:-

```
cd \
set "d=One Space"
for /F "usebackq delims=#" %F in (`powershell -command "& {Get-ChildItem \"%d%\"}"`) do (echo %F)

set "e=Multiple         Space"
for /F "usebackq delims=#" %F in (`powershell -command "& {Get-ChildItem \"%e%\"}"`) do (echo %F)
```

Can someone explain or provide solution for executing command whose path have multiple spaces?

Comment: So you want to create the folder with multiple spaces?

Comment: @gerhard. Yes. The actual problem scenario is different but root cause boils down to consecutive spaces in file path.

Comment: Your question title and tag are specific, in that this is a batch file question. Where is your [tag:batch-file]? What you've posted are individual commands for [tag:cmd], and are you sure that using back quotes to change the behavior of quotes in the [tag:for-loop] is a good idea. Finally what are you really trying to achieve, because that [tag:powershell] command is obviously not correct, and I doubt that asking a generic question, and hoping to adapt it later yourself is a wise idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can just use single quotes to keep the multiple spaces:

```
cd \
set "d=One Space"
for /F "usebackq delims=#" %F in (`powershell -command "& {Get-ChildItem \'%d%\'}"`) do (echo %F)

set "e=Multiple         Space"
for /F "usebackq delims=#" %F in (`powershell -command "& {Get-ChildItem \'%e%\'}"`) do (echo %F)
```